# Copy formatted string to new cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, colors

I want to copy dynamic string colors to a new cell, keeping the formatting.
[image: [Screencap of Table](https://imgur.com/O8ui38E)]

We copy and paste a lot of a particular cell to another and the individually colored text strings do not stay the proper colors.

I was under the assumption that these texts would be static. That is not the case.

```vb
Sub FormatCopying()

'turn off green selection
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'copies text
Range("A1:D10").Copy Range("F1:H9")

'copies cell format
Range("A1:D10").Copy
Range("F1:H9").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

'turns on green selection; never appeared as it was off and now it is on
Application.CutCopyMode = True

'color red and bold "test to see if I can"
Dim RedColor1 As Long
Dim RedColor1End As Integer

RedColor1 = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "test to see if I can", vbTextCompare)
RedColor1End = Len("test to see if I can")
If RedColor1 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(RedColor1, RedColor1End).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
If RedColor1 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(RedColor1, RedColor1End).Font.Bold = True

'color blue and bold "do this"
Dim BlueColor1 As Long
Dim BlueColor1End As Integer

BlueColor1 = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "do this", vbTextCompare)
BlueColor1End = Len("do this")
If BlueColor1 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(BlueColor1, BlueColor1End).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
If BlueColor1 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(BlueColor1, BlueColor1End).Font.Bold = True

'color red and bold "Who knows."
Dim RedColor2 As Long
Dim RedColor2End As Integer

RedColor2 = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "Who knows.", vbTextCompare)
RedColor2End = Len("Who knows.")
If RedColor2 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(RedColor2, RedColor2End).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
If RedColor2 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(RedColor2, RedColor2End).Font.Bold = True

'color black and bold "Guess we'll find out."
Dim BlackColor1 As Long
Dim BlackColor1End As Integer

BlackColor1 = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "Guess we'll find out.", vbTextCompare)
BlackColor1End = Len("Guess we'll find out.")
If BlackColor1 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(BlackColor1, BlackColor1End).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
If BlackColor1 > 0 Then ActiveCell.Characters(BlackColor1, BlackColor1End).Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are there merged cells in those ranges?  Can't tell from the screenshot.  A straight copy/paste will copy the range exactly as-is (including text color, bold etc), so it's difficult to tell exactly what the problem is you're trying to solve here.

Comment: `Range("A1:D10").Copy Range("F1:H9")` overwrites the cells of `F1:I11`. It is different with your target area (range).

Comment: What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: @ted williams Yes, there are merged cells that are different sizes :)  You are correct; copying will keep the format.  I was tired and got my wires crossed.  The original file was referencing the cells (which never keeps formatting).  I slept on it and I could maybe unmerge, copy, and then remerge the other merged cells.  I never do things this way as you have to do dual maintenance with odd colorings (unless it's a template that never changes).

Comment: @ted willians Update, yep that worked, I'll post my solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR, my approach was flawed and I cannot give the solution way my coworkers think it should go, but I can give them the result they want.  I just recorded a Macro to unmerge the locations, copy upper left of the original cell to the upper left of the destination cell, and then remerge the cells.  Thanks to all who commented and helped out!

```
Sub Merge_FormatCopy()

'Merge_FormatCopy Macro

'Unmerge Origin
    Range("A1:D10").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
    
'Unmerge Destination
    Range("F1:H9").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.UnMerge
    
'Copy Upper Left of Orgin Merged Cell
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
'Paste Upper Left of Destination Merged Cell
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
'Remerge Orign Cells
    Range("A1:D10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
'Remerge Destination Cells
    Selection.Merge
    Range("F1:H9").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
End Sub
```